# Dojo promise all -- but that waits for all promises to return

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo, promise

I am using dojo promises, with deferred. I have a promise/all that catches all of the promises and only executes when they are all successful or when any one of them returns an error. Is there a way to have a list of promises that only returns when all are executed(regardless if they were successful or error)? I'd like to have a list of the ones that failed, instead of "one of these failed".

I guess I could just resolve all of the deferreds, error or success, but that kinda defeats the purpose...

Answer (score 4):

There are two alternatives for this:

#### Settle

Dojo promises offer no tools for managing this case explicitly ala' bluebird's `Promise.settle` or when's `when.settle`. So we pretty much have to create it ourselves:

```
function settle(promises){ // assuming "dojo/promise/all" and "dojo/Deferred"
    var d = new Deferred();
    var countdownLatch = promises.length; 
    var results = [];
    promises.forEach(function(p, i){ 
        p.then(function(v){
            results[i] = {state: "fulfilled", value: v};
            countdownLatch--;
            if(countdownLatch === 0) d.resolve(results);
        }, function(err){
            results[i] = {state: "rejected", err: err };
            countdownLatch--;
            if(countdownLatch === 0) d.resolve(results);
        });
    });
    return d; // dojo mixes deferred and promises because it's an older API
}
```

This would let you do:

```
settle(myPromisesArray).then(function(results){
    results.forEach(function(res){
        console.log(res.state); // you can `if` on it to check a particular promise
    });
});
```

#### Reflect

A more modern approach is to create a reflect method that takes a promise and returns a promise that always fulfills with an object containing the previous promise's state. This is a direction Bluebird is exploring and will possibly be included in V3.

```
function reflect(promise){
    return promise.then(function(v){ return {state: "fulfilled", value: v }; },
                        function(e){ return {state: "rejected" , error: e }; });
}
```

Which would let you do different aggregations, this makes `settle` from above a private case with:

```
function settle(promises){
    return all(promises.map(reflect));
}
```

Comment: @Skitterm just an example of a modern promise library (two orders of magnitude faster, better traces etc)

Comment: According to [this page](https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2015/03/06/understanding-deferreds-and-promises-in-dojo/), you should return `deferred.promise` instead of `deferred`, (`d.promise` in your case)

Answer (score 0):

As you've found, dojo/promise/all is fulfilled as soon as one of the constituent promises is cancelled.

You want dojo/DeferredList - this can be configured to do what you want, and you can extract the promise object from it.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, DeferredList is deprecated.

Comment: Yep.  If you're not intending to upgrade to Dojo 2.0, though, you'll be fine.

Comment: ... and surprise, no Dojo 2.0 still :)

Comment: @NickMaynard [2.0 release is planned for this month](https://github.com/dojo/meta/wiki/Roadmap)